# What can update this viewpager?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a page adapter with two pages from sherlockfragment,
but when I change page from one to two, the page doesn't update and the screen is a white page.

My adapter page code is:

```
public class VpiAbsTestActivitynouser extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] {" 1","2"};

TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
 ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

    mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

}



class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {        
    private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {

        case 0:

            return new customlistnotuser();

        case 1:

            return new anotherpage();


        default:
            return null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }


    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return VpiAbsTestActivitynouser.CONTENT[position % VpiAbsTestActivitynouser.CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
    }

     @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
             ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
        }



 }
```

}

And my fragment looks like this:

```
 public class customlistnotuser extends SherlockFragment  {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "url";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_TEST = "test"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_Description = "description";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";



 private ProgressDialog pDialog;


ListView list;
LazyAdapterbeth adapter;
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


}



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new getFeed().execute();

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

    View thisfragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dovomi, container, false);

    return thisfragment;
}



private class getFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {



       }

    protected Document doInBackground(Void... params) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        return doc;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TEST);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_Description, parser.getValue(e, KEY_Description));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
        map.put(KEY_PRICE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRICE));
        map.put(KEY_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_URL));
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
         pDialog.dismiss();
    }



    list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapterbeth(getActivity(), songsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
```

How do I update my view when I go from page one to page two?

how can i use instantiateItem and notifyDataSetChanged(); on this code to update view ?

Comment: show the new page but it dont show only page one is show

Comment: What new page? Your `ViewPager` has the exact fragment for both pages so unless you have another mechanism for seeing which fragment belongs to which page they will all be the same.

Comment: no when i change the page two for example return new another(); dont show to me this new page

Comment: how can i use instantiateItem and notifyDataSetChanged(); on this code to update view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your Fragments needs to return a instance of the Fragment, you can do this by adding a newInstance(Bundle args); Then you can update the Fragment depending on the postion in the ViewPager with FragmentArguments.

```
public class CustomList extends SherlockListFragment{
int fragment_position_in_viewpager = 0;
....
public static CustomList newInstance(Bundle args) {
customlist fragment = new CustomList();
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}
....

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if (getArguments() != null) {
    fragment_position_in_viewpager = getArguments().getInt("position"); 
} 
String[] params = {xmlURLArray[fragment_position_in_viewpager]}

new getFeed().execute(params);

}

protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(params[0]); // getting XML from URL
....



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.layout_custom_list, container, false);

    //initialize your widgets here
    //button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

final int fragment_position_in_viewpager;
if (getArguments() != null) {
    fragment_position_in_viewpager = getArguments().getInt("position"); 
} 

     //Update the Fragment UI depending on the ViewPager Position.

....
```

Then in your TestFragmentAdapter (FragmentPagerAdaper)

```
....
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

         //Return a Fragment
        //from a new Instance with FragmentArguments
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("position", position);
            return CustomList.newInstance(args);

//use a switch if you have different types Fragments
//switch(position) {
    //case 0:
        //From the Fragment Constructor 
            //    return (mCustomList = new CustomList());
....
```

Comment: thanx for code i use it but my view Yet not update and i can see page one and page two is empty ... how update view when change pages?

Comment: my view is    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 

    {
     
        View thisfragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dovomi, container, false);
        
        return thisfragment;
    }

Comment: Have you inflated your layout in onCreateView() and then you will need to update your View in onViewCreated()

Comment: please tell me how can i update view in  onViewCreated() i really confused !

Comment: Example: Let your Fragment extend SherlockListFragment instead since you use ListView, then in onViewCreated() populate your LazyAdapterbeth adapter depending on the position you get from the getArguments() and give the adapter to your listview with setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: See updated answer for onCreate(): 
if (getArguments() != null) {
    fragment_position_in_viewpager = getArguments().getInt("position"); 
} 
String[] params = {xmlURLArray[fragment_position_in_viewpager]}
new getFeed().execute(params);
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22662/discussion-between-hsigmond-and-user1524393)